# How to determine which columns to index in a SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008, indexing

I have a program written in VB.NET with a SQL Server database, to manage my electric engines' system, where I have about 15000 records in my database till now and as I'm filling data more and more, my queries started to slow down exponentially.

I decided to solve that issue by indexing, however I don't know how to determine which columns to index in a multi-table-column query like this below (it takes about 16 sec):

```
SELECT 
    r.ID as [المعرّف],
    ch.ID as [معرّف القيمة],
    r.active as [مفعّل],
    en.ename as [الموتور],
    b.location as [عنوان العلبة],
    c.clientname as [المشترك],
    p.ampere as [أمبير],
    cl.fullname as [الجابي],
    b.code as [رمز العلبة],
    ec.code as [الرمز في العلبة],
    ch.previousvalue as [القيمة السابقة],
    ch.currentvalue as [القيمة الحاليّة],
    r.insurance as [تأمين],
    ((SELECT SUM(total) 
      FROM CounterHistory coh 
      WHERE coh.regid = r.ID 
        AND (coh.cyear < 2018 OR (coh.cmonth < 1 and coh.cyear = 2018))) - 
     (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(pyy.pvalue), 0) 
      FROM CounterHistory coh, Payment pyy 
      WHERE pyy.counterhistoryid = coh.ID 
        AND coh.regid = r.ID 
        AND (coh.cyear < 2018 OR (coh.cmonth < 1 and coh.cyear = 2018)))) AS [مكسورات],
    ch.notes as [ملاحظات],
    (CAST(ar.caption as nvarchar(50)) + '-' + CAST(ch.cyear as nvarchar(50))) as [شهر],(b.code + ec.code) as [رمز مفتاح],ch.monthlyfee as [رسم اشتراك],
    (ch.currentvalue-ch.previousvalue) as [فرق عداد],
    ch.kilowattprice as [سعر الكيلو],
    (((ch.currentvalue-ch.previousvalue)*ch.kilowattprice) + roundvalue) as [مطلوب كيلو],
    total+discount as [المجموع],
    discount as [حسم],
    (SELECT IsNull(Sum(pyy.pvalue),0) FROM CounterHistory coh,Payment pyy WHERE pyy.counterhistoryid=coh.ID and coh.regid=r.ID AND coh.cmonth =1 and  coh.cyear=2018) as [مدفوع],
    (total - (SELECT IsNull(Sum(pyy.pvalue),0) FROM CounterHistory coh, Payment pyy WHERE pyy.counterhistoryid=coh.ID and coh.regid=r.ID AND coh.cmonth = 1 and coh.cyear=2018)) AS [باقي]
FROM 
    Registration r, Client c, ElectricBox b, ECounter ec,
    CounterHistory ch, Package p, Engine en, Collector cl, ArabicMonth ar 
WHERE 
    r.packageid = p.ID 
    AND ch.cmonth = ar.ID 
    AND r.counterid = ec.ID 
    AND ec.boxid = b.ID 
    AND r.clientid = c.ID 
    AND ch.regid = r.ID 
    AND b.engineid = en.ID 
    AND b.collectorid = cl.ID 
    AND ch.cmonth = 1 
    AND ch.cyear = 2018 
    AND (DatePart("yyyy", r.registrationdate) < 2018 OR (DatePart("m", r.registrationdate) <= 1 AND DatePart("yyyy", r.registrationdate) = 2018)) 
ORDER BY 
    cl.fullname, b.code, ec.code
```

So **how to determine which columns to index** in a query like this, and is there any way to optimize it (if possible)?!

Here is my database build query:

```
create table ArabicMonth (ID INT primary key, caption varchar(50) not null);
create table Client (ID INT IDENtity(1,1) primary key,clientname varchar(255) not null,clientnickname varchar(255),clientmothername varchar(255),caddress varchar(255),phone varchar(50),mobile varchar(50));
create table Collector (ID INT IDENtity(1,1) primary key,fullname varchar(255) not null,caddress varchar(255),phone varchar(50),mobile varchar(50),notes varchar(1000));
create table CounterHistory (ID INT IDENtity(1,1) primary key,cmonth int not null,cyear int not null,regid int default 0,monthlyfee int default 0,kilowattprice int default 0,previousvalue int default 0,currentvalue int default 0,roundvalue int default 0,discount int default 0,total as [monthlyfee]+([kilowattprice]*([currentvalue]-[previousvalue]))+[roundvalue]-[discount],notes varchar(1000));
create table ECounter (ID INT IDENtity(1,1) primary key,serial varchar(255) not null,code varchar(5),boxid int not null default 0,active bit default 0,notes varchar(1000));
create table ElectricBox (ID INT IDENtity(1,1) primary key,code varchar(10) not null,location varchar(255),collectorid int not null,engineid int not null,notes varchar(1000));
create table Engine (ID INT IDENtity(1,1) primary key,ename varchar(255) not null,location varchar(255),epower varchar(255),company varchar(255),contactphone varchar(255),repairparty varchar(255),notes varchar(1000));
create table EngineWorkingHours (engineid int not null,cmonth int not null,cyear int not null,workinghours int default 0,notes varchar(255), primary key(engineid,cmonth,cyear));
create table Expenditure (ID INT IDENtity(1,1) primary key,expdate date not null,title varchar(255),amount int default 0,party varchar(255),detail varchar(1000));
create table Package (ID INT IDENtity(1,1) primary key,ampere decimal not null,fee int not null,insurance int not null,kilowattprice int not null,notes varchar(1000));
create table Payment (ID INT IDENtity(1,1) primary key,counterhistoryid int not null,pdate datetime not null,pvalue int not null,notes varchar(1000),collector varchar(50));
create table Registration (ID INT IDENtity(1,1) primary key,clientid int not null,registrationdate date not null,packageid int not null,counterid int not null,active bit default 0,initialcountervalue int not null,enddate date,insurance int default 0,notes varchar(1000));
create table Notes(ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL primary key,ExpiryDate date NOT NULL,ExpiryTime time NOT NULL,nStatus varchar(255) NULL,NoteDetail varchar(1000) NULL)

alter table EngineWorkingHours add constraint fk_EngineWorkingHours foreign key (engineid) references Engine(ID);
alter table ElectricBox add constraint fk_ElectricBoxEngine foreign key (engineid) references Engine(ID);
alter table ElectricBox add constraint fk_ElectricBoxCollector foreign key (collectorid) references Collector(ID);
alter table ECounter add constraint fk_ECounterElectricBox foreign key (boxid) references ElectricBox(ID);
alter table Registration add constraint fk_RegistrationECounter foreign key (counterid) references ECounter(ID);
alter table Registration add constraint fk_RegistrationPackage foreign key (packageid) references Package(ID);
alter table Registration add constraint fk_RegistrationClient foreign key (clientid) references Client(ID);
alter table CounterHistory add constraint fk_CounterHistoryRegistration foreign key (regid) references Registration(ID);
alter table CounterHistory add constraint fk_CounterHistoryArabicMonth foreign key (cmonth) references ArabicMonth(ID);
alter table Payment add constraint fk_PaymentCounterHistory foreign key (counterhistoryid) references CounterHistory(ID);
```

***Thanks in advance!!***

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: thanks @marc_s for that, i know how to do it with JOIN syntax but I thought that it doesn't affect the speed, do you think that this is slowing down my query?

Comment: The way to determine whether there's a difference in speed between the two syntaxes is to test both syntaxes.

Comment: 15 000 records is nothing. your tables aren't that big. are you still running Sybase? on a old 80386?

Comment: Show estimated execution plan in and include actual execution when running your query. You can see what is using table scan or index scan. And as the others have pointed out, use the proper JOINs.

Comment: 10786335 row(s) returned / 46.094 sec on MySQL that's 235 000 line a sec in 1.5GB

Comment: Without seeing your execution plan it is hard to tell. But why are you doing "AND (DatePart("yyyy", r.registrationdate) < 2018 OR (DatePart("m", r.registrationdate) <= 1 AND DatePart("yyyy", r.registrationdate) = 2018))" instead of "r.registrationdate < '2018-02-1'? Not only is it three functions plus three comparisons instead of one comparison for every row, if you did have a date index it couldn't use it.

Comment: Short answer: all columns in the `WHERE` and `FROM` clauses are good candidates but what combination of them will produce best results depends on your specific data. Take note of @DancingFool comment.

Comment: thanks all for your reply, i will take all of your notes into consideration, give it a try and will post back the results